# How to integrate DexieJs in Angular2

Tags: angular, dexie

I got this error when I try to run and code related to Dexie.

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: ReferenceError: require is not defined
        at eval (http://localhost:3001/vendor/traceur/dist/commonjs/traceur.js:5:92)
    Evaluating http://localhost:3001/vendor/traceur/dist/commonjs/traceur.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3001/vendor/traceur/dist/commonjs/traceur.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3001/vendor/dexie/dist/dexie.js as "dexie" from http://localhost:3001/app/pages/portal/portal.js ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: ReferenceError: require is not defined(…)
```

Just by declaring a Database, I already have the above errors.

```
// Declare Database 

class FriendDatabase extends Dexie {
    friends: Dexie.Table<IFriend,number>;   

    constructor() {
        super("FriendDatabase");
        this.version(1).stores({
            friends: "++id,name,age"
        });
    }
}
```

The convention way of me adding Dexie is in systemjs.config.js(in my case I've used Typescipt)

```
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
  'dexie': 'vendor/dexie/dist',
  'traceur': 'vendor/traceur/dist/commonjs'

};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'dexie': { main: 'dexie.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
  'traceur': { main: 'traceur.js', defaultExtension: 'js'}
};
```

**Edited**
My src code can be found [here](https://github.com/maclarensg/angular2-rails5/tree/master/angular2/src)

**Edited**

Just to be clear. I'm not saying it is dexie's library issue. It could be that I'm not implementing in the right way. Hence, looking for a guide to implement dexie correctly in angular2.

**Edited**

I found this [link](https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/issues/187), but the solution of adding the below code doesn't work for me

```
System.register("dexie", [], true, function(require, exports, module) {
  var global = System.global,
      __define = global.define;
 global.define = undefined;
(function (global, factory) {
....
```

**(Work around)**

Not what, I'm able to barely get it working is by add dexie via script tag
`<script src="vendor/dexie/dist/dexie.min.js"></script>`
and then I can work with dexie straightaway.

But the problem to this is that I cannot import dexie and all the typings for dexie is missing.

I try to manual copy dexie.d.ts and reference it, but typescript does not acknowledge, so I would have compilation errors.

Comment: You're telling that you use TS, but both config and error message tell that you use Traceur. Please, elaborate on that. Any way, it seems to do nothing with Dexie library itself, just with SystemJS configuration (which was truncated, by the way).

Comment: The only reason why my config has tracecur is that if I do not include it in my systemjs configuration, it would still request for tracecur anyways and resulted in a 404, as long as I import dexie and define a database as shown in my example. By including tracecur, it resulted to the above error. So hence, I looking for a guide how to integrate Dexie correctly into angular2

Comment: If you use Typescript, you don't need Traceur (unless you absolutely certain that you do). I guess that SystemJS uses Traceur by default, and you haven't configured it properly. The problem isn't related to the library, please, update the question with all the relevant information on how you use SystemJS.

Comment: I've include my [src code](https://github.com/maclarensg/angular2-rails5/tree/master/angular2/src)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after some googling.

In order to configure Dexie with SystemJS is found in this github [link.](https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/issues/257)

**Copy the summary here**

Install dexie via npm

```
npm install dexie --save
```

Update systemjs.config.js as follows:

```
Add 'dexie': 'node_modules/dexie/dist/dexie.js' to map.
Add 'dexie': { format: 'amd' } to packages.
```

Also: Make sure your tsconfig file has "moduleResolution": "node".